# How Razor Components communicate with the server app

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

For a blazor (client side hosting), client app can send request to web server via webapi. But for Razor Components (aka server side blazor), what is the proper way to let components access the server, say a db in server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty is that you don't have to do anything special. Just make a method that opens a EF context, that will work. Blazor will take care of the transport. You don't have to expose an API or anything.

Answer (score 1):

When using Razor Components you can either use a Web API as in the case of Blazor web browser application, or you can create, for instance, a service which access the database, and pass the data to the calling components. Personally, I wouldn't recommend employing the latter because this approach may hinder your ability to switch between Blazor and Razor applications, presently mainly because Razor Components allow you to easily debug your app, while in Blazor debugging is almost meaningless.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried and it works. I have also found the following article that do exactly what you advised: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51872.blazor-single-page-application-using-server-side-blazor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to use Entity Framework Core (EF Core) in server-side Blazor apps:

[ASP.NET Core Blazor with Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

#### TL;DR

> The recommended approach to create a new DbContext with dependencies is to use a factory. EF Core 5.0 or later provides a built-in factory for creating new contexts.

Configure DI:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ContactContext>(opt =>
    opt.UseSqlite($"Data Source={nameof(ContactContext.ContactsDb)}.db"));
```

Get factory by injection:

```
@inject IDbContextFactory<ContactContext> DbFactory
```